# fatal error LNK1112: module machine type 'X86' conflicts with target machine type 'x64' during npm install

Tags: c++, node.js, dll, electron, npm-install

I am writing code to load c++ dll from electron. My dll is 32 bit. I am using NaN and bindings to achieve this. I used the following commands to set build for 32 bit:

```
node-gyp clean configure build --verbose --arch=ia32 
npm set npm_config_arch ia32
npm install --arch=ia32 electron-prebuilt -g
```

When I run npm install I get the following error:

fatal error LNK1112: module machine type 'X86' conflicts with target machine type 'x64'

Although I am able to build and run my module with the following command:

```
electron-rebuild -f -w yourmodule --arch=ia32
```

But I am wondering why npm install fails.

Comment: What you've posted is a warning, not an error...

Comment: Sorry I added line from wrong project. Added correct error statement

Answer (score 0):

The below works for me

```
npm set npm_config_arch ia32
npm clean-install --arch=ia32
```

The first command set the node environment to 32bit.
The second command re-install all the node packages that are 32bit compatible.