# Setting custom path for required dll files: electron app

Tags: c++, dll, electron, node-gyp

I am writing code to load c++ dll from electron.I am using NaN and bindings (node-gyp) to achieve this. I run the following command to build my node module:

electron-rebuild -f -w yourmodule --arch=ia32

This command creates a Release folder inside build folder where the built .node module is saved. To run my application I need to copy all the dependent dlls to the Release folder. The problem is every time I rebuild my module, all the copied dlls are deleted from Release folder. Is there a way by which I can set custom path for the required dlls?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can add a `copies` section to your binding.gyp file so that your dlls are copied to the ".node" file location every build.

```
{ 
  "targets": [
    {
      "conditions":[
        ["OS=='win'", {
          "copies":
            [
              {
                'destination': '<(module_root_dir)/build/Release',
                'files': [
                  '<(module_root_dir)/yourdllfile1.dll',
                  '<(module_root_dir)/yourdllfile2.dll',
                ]
              }
            ]
        }]
      ]
    }
  ]
}
```

Comment: Thanks a lot. It worked. Can you also help me with the following question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56768227/fatal-error-lnk1112-module-machine-type-x86-conflicts-with-target-machine-typ

Comment: How can I copy to multiple locations from here?

Comment: You can add another dictionary to the "copies" section. Another dictionary with "destination" and "files" keywords.